# Hide Mouse Pointer on Android

Tags: java, android, mouse-cursor, ouya

I'm writing a game for OUYA and Android and I'm using the trackpad on the OUYA controller.  When ever you touch it a mouse pointer comes up and I can't find a way to hide it.  I image this would be a problem for games on an Android netbook as well.

Has anyone found a way to interact with the cursor instead of just listening for events?

Comment: Seems to be an issue on both the Java and Unity sides: http://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/comment/2968 You may want to chime in on that discussion, or start a new one, as I think those forums get a bit more official love than does SO.

Comment: Yeah, I read that thread and from what I gather there is no JNI connection to allow that from Unity.  I'm just using Java so I thought I'd post here and see if there was a general Android solution.

Answer (score 6):

This won't hide the mouse, but it will at least help prevent touch events from interfering with your joystick processing code -- not a proper solution I know, but still might help people who land on this page:

```
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if ( (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK) != 0) {
        //handle the event
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to override this for my NativeActivity. I can override for onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() but when trying to override the motion func, I get: "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Answer (score 2):

Android currently does not expose any functionality to hide the mouse cursor.  Whenever you have an external pointing device (ie. usb/bluetooth mouse, trackpad, etc) a mouse pointer will appear on the screen whenever you interact with the device.

Unfortunately (as of JB 4.2.2) this means it is impossible without a modified ROM.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to [request pointer capture](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement#pointer-capture) now. You need to explicitly request capture:

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
    view.requestPointerCapture()
}
```

As documented:

> Android delivers pointer events from sources other than the mouse normally, but the mouse pointer is not visible anymore.

You can either handle pointer events by overriding `onCapturedPointerEvent`:

```
override fun onCapturedPointerEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // Get the coordinates required by your app
    val verticalOffset: Float = motionEvent.y
    // Use the coordinates to update your view and return true if the event was
    // successfully processed
    return true
}
```

or registering an event handler for `OnCapturedPointerListener`:

```
myView.setOnCapturedPointerListener { view, motionEvent ->
    // Get the coordinates required by your app
    val horizontalOffset: Float = motionEvent.x
    // Use the coordinates to update your view and return true if the event was
    // successfully processed
    true
}
```

And it's up to you to release the pointer when you're done:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    view.releasePointerCapture()
}
```

I know that the context of this question overall may not apply (ie: Ouya development), but this was the first search result when I looked into how to do this myself. So I figured that I'd update the answer!